# Организация миграций

Tags: миграция

В свободное время делаю на коленке проект, благодаря чему могу сделать все правильно и красиво. Начал делать миграции, встал вопрос - насколько атомарными они должны быть, чтобы исправление структуры БД в ручном режиме было достаточно маловероятным, как их группировать - по одной миграции на таблицу от создания до fk или группировать операции по типу, чтобы не рвать транзакцию, где это возможно*? Понятно, что никаких стандартов не существует, но хотелось бы сделать все максимально безграбельно.
Бонусом можно рассказать любые поучительные истории про миграции.

* Например, мне нужно создать таблицы users и users_oauth c fk и какими-нибудь индексами. Лучше будет:
а) Запихнуть в отдельные миграции создание двух таблиц, проставление индексов и fk? (группировка по типу операции)
б) Запихнуть в отдельные миграции создание, индексы и fk каждой таблицы? (логическая группировка)
в) Запихнуть каждую операцию в отдельную миграцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считаю, что тут как с коммитами в системах контроля версий: одно логическое изменение - одна миграция.

Цель миграций ведь в том, чтобы поддерживать базы команды разработчиков и на серверах после деплоя в актуальном состоянии, а также иметь возможность отката кода вместе с откатом изменений в БД. Поэтому если таблицы users и users_oauth создаются одновременно и не имеют смысла друг без друга, то и разделять их на отдельные миграции нет смысла. Можно ориентироваться на название миграции: если вы не можете дать краткое название миграции, то, вероятно, ее стоит разделить на более атомарные.

Comment: > Поэтому если таблицы users и users_oauth создаются одновременно и не имеют смысла друг без друга, то и разделять их на отдельные миграции нет смысла.

Чего я боюсь (и ради чего я затеял этот пост): что сначала выполнится команда, которая рвет транзакцию (тот же create table), а затем по тем или иным причинам обвалится миграция целиком. Или, наоборот, в откате миграции случится что-то подобное. В идеале даже в процессе разработки я не должен лезть руками в базу и править то, что начудил, и этот подход, к сожалению, обвалится в тот момент, как я забуду дропнуть какой-нибудь fk.

Comment: Миграции ведь перед тем, как попасть к другим, отлаживаются локально. Пока вы ее у себя пишите, нет ничего страшного выполнять ее непосредственно в БД, проверять запросы отката, пока не добьетесь безошибочного выполнения.

И если структура базы одинаковая у всех участников, почему после этого должны возникнуть где-то проблемы?

Comment: @vanchester, это единоличный проект, делаю себе хомяка наконец. Меня напрягает лезть в базу руками, если я все делаю совсем из другого места. Получается, что миграции вроде и есть, а работаю всего равно через пгадмина.  
Ну и в идеале хотелось, чтоб я такой хопа - и с постгреса на мускул прыгнул, потом на sqlite, затем надел солнцезащитные очки и укатил в закат.

Comment: Миграции ведь не для того предназначены, чтобы в базу не лезть, а чтобы упростить перенос изменений БД, и, как дополнительный бонус, - сохранять историю изменений БД

Comment: а что касается вашего желания не использовать другие инструменты, так в современных IDE есть все для работы с БД. Использую в работе PHPStorm, и очень активно пользуюсь его редактором Database